# When to use dynamicfield in gridview?

Tags: asp.net

Allow me to ask a stupid question about dynamicfield. When and why to use it? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Represents a data field displayed in a data-bound control that uses ASP.NET Dynamic Data features.

ASP.NET Dynamic Data is a framework that lets you easily create ASP.NET Web applications data-driven. To do this, it automatically metadata data model and runtime deduce the behavior of the user interface..

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.dynamicdata.dynamicfield.aspx

Comment: Isn't this more a comment than an answer? ([_rtfm_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM))

Comment: Yes i added answer and link, if link become not avaiable

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What are the Dynamic Data features?

Comment: @Frank : ASP.NET Dynamic Data is a framework that lets you easily create ASP.NET Web applications data-driven. To do this, it automatically metadata data model and runtime deduce the behavior of the user interface.